# Convert HTML-5 Template into MVC-5 Application: Project Structure

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, nuget

I primarily work on Business Layer / DAl Layer & am big fan of Nuget. I am sorry if this sounds to obvious.
My company bought a new HTML-5 template.

I am converting this into an MVC-5 application. This template uses popular JavaScript/CSS libraries popular today (e.g. Bootstrap / Modernizr etc.) Rather than relying on template version & path of libraries, I manually install all these packages from Nuget & replace all occurrences to point to Nuget version. So that tomorrow, I could run `Update-Package` command simply to get latest version.

I am wondering: am I following the right path. What is the good practice to convert ready-made HTML-5 template to MVC-5 application?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I'd advice you to start the other way round. Converting pure HTML to MVC is just about replacing pure HMTL tags from you template with MVC tags in right places (and these places depends on what your app actually does).
Start with _layout.cshtml (if I remember correctly) as it contains page skeleton (`<html> <body>` tags), and then work your way down to patial views.
I recommend you this way, because if you're not really into asp.net MVC you might find it hard to rebuild the template from scratch.